# Playback doesn't work (including test sounds) / Recording works / Playback in Chrome works!

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audacity, playback

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit in a virtual machine. I have a very odd issue with media playback. audio playback doesn't work from an app. the test sounds in "Sound" settings don't work -- but only after i try to play a file! what's also perplexing is that any media playback through my web browser -- Google Chrome -- works!

Recording audio works through my USB microphone.

A hint of where to start would be great :) thanks!

**update**

i have followed the advice at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

after running: 
`killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*`
and restarting, i went immediately to "Test Sounds" and woolah -- the sound works.

however, opening any media playback app -- Rhythmbox, Audacity, Movie Player, etc. -- results in some sort of bug immediately after playback. In Audacity, for example, this manifests as a brief movement across 1-2 seconds worth of waveform, and a "freezing" of the playback... other programs also simply 'freeze', and no sound ever emits from the speaker.

additionally, if i return to the "test sound" after trying to play a WAV or MP3 in a media playback app, the test sound buttons no longer work. funnily, audio from Chrome is still possible!

i also tried: `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r`libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r`libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status; sudo usermod -aG`cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'whoami`` to no avail (it didn't work, same problem exists)

Comment: Go to Ubuntu Software. Search for **PulseAudio Volume Control**. Install it and open it from dash. You can see the different audio streams playing. Switch the drop down from the bottom to **show** All Streams. This will help you in understanding. If some of the audio streams are actually playing but are just muted, you can unmute it and check

Comment: I have added the PulseAudio Volume Control, but a muted stream isn't the issue :/ (playback works in Chrome, but in no other app) -- see update: test sound also works on fresh startup, but not after playback attempts